# GT tables summary row based on data from another df or list

Tags: r, quarto, gt

I am trying to create summary rows in gt table with reference to another data source.

I have df results that I want to print with summary rows:

```
results <- data.frame(level = c("LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "LQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC", "HQC"),
                     source = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                     val_A = c(30.1822, 33.0850, 32.2722, 27.7168, 29.1946, 29.1808, 33.1962, 32.6243, 31.7900, 1799.5074, 2012.0351, 2054.0858, 1956.2820, 1990.6278, 2081.3730, 1955.4075, 2073.8068, 2076.9238),
                     val_B = c(3.6880, 3.8021, 3.5833, 3.4146, 2.7805, 3.1428, 2.9596, 4.0376, 3.9008, 362.4901, 331.9178, 337.8255, 324.2157, 336.1455, 342.8927, 317.3914, 334.1520, 338.8625))
```

There is also df with reference value:

```
reference <- data.frame(level  = c("LQC", "HQC"),
                  val_A = c(30, 2000),
                  val_B = c(3, 400))
```

I need to generate a table, preferably using gt, that contains summaries grouped by level and source.
Had no problem with average and RSD. Table looks good (code below) and itis what I want.

```
res_tab <- results |> 
  group_by(level, source) |>
  gt()|> 
  summary_rows(columns = matches("val_"),
               fns = list(id = "mean", label = "Mean", fn = "mean"),
               fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2)) |> 
  summary_rows(columns = matches("val_"),
               fns = list(id = "cv", label = "CV", fn = ~sd(.)/mean(.)*100),
               fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2, pattern = "{x}%"))|> 
  fmt_number(columns = matches("val_"),
             decimals = 2)
```

But I also need accuracy, so I need to divide the reference value by the mean of the group.

I tried to divide problem into two separate tables for different levels (it is acceptable). Then I would only have to referebce column with only one row (or convert it to list). My idea was to use `cur_column()` like this:

```
results_LQC <- results |> 
  filter(level == "LQC") |> 
  select(-level)
  
reference_LQC <- reference |> 
  filter(level == "LQC") |> 
  select(-level)

res_LQC_tab <- results_LQC |> 
  group_by(source) |>
  gt()|> 
  summary_rows(columns = matches("val_"),
               fns = list(id = "mean", label = "Mean", fn = "mean"),
               fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2)) |> 
  summary_rows(columns = matches("val_"),
               fns = list(id = "acc", label = "Accuracy", fn = ~mean(.)/reference_LQC[[cur_column()]]*100),
               fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2, pattern = "{x}%"))|>
  summary_rows(columns = matches("val_"),
               fns = list(id = "cv", label = "CV", fn = ~sd(.)/mean(.)*100),
               fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2, pattern = "{x}%"))|> 
  fmt_number(columns = matches("val_"),
             decimals = 2)
```

Unfortunately, cur_column does not work in GT (but it definitely should! - I'm going to fill feature request).

And now I'm stuck. Help needed.

Ideal solution would allow to reference both column and row matching level and do it in one table for both levels.

Best regards.
Radek